# Create a function that will remove all occurences from a letter from a string

Tags: python

What am i doing wrong? the output should be 'pple', 'bnn' , 'banana'

```
  def remove_letter(theLetter, theString):
    theString = list(theString)
    newString = []
    for i in range(len(theString)):
        if theString[i]!= theLetter:
            newString.append(theString[i])
        print(theLetter)


remove_letter("bananna", "n") == "bnn" 
remove_letter("apple","a") == "pple" 
remove_letter("banana","z") == "banana"
```

Comment: For the first case, do you mean the output should be "baaa"? Or is the letter "a" instead? When you called your "remove_letter" function, the order of the arguments are flipped. You should call it like `remove_letter("a", "apple"). Additionally, you should `return newString` after and on the same scope as the `for` loop. Otherwise, the function won't have an output!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a loop in this case, you simply have to replace the letter with nothing at all. This can quite easily be done using `replace()`, like so:

```
def removeLetter(letter, string):
    return string.replace(letter, '')

print(removeLetter('a', 'apple'))
print(removeLetter('n', 'banana'))
print(removeLetter('a', 'banana'))
```

Giving an output of:

```
pple
baaa
bnn
```

This also works if the letter is not present within the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_letter(theLetter, theString):
...
remove_letter("bananna", "n") == "bnn"
```

See the discrepancy between the ordering in your function definition and how the function is called. Also, I think you meant to remove `"a"` here

```
remove_letter("a", "banana") == "bnn"
```

Next, your function does not return anything, therefore it really returns `None`. Have your function `return str(newString)`

Finally, this is a good opportunity to learn about list comprehensions!

```
def remove_letter(theLetter, theString):
    retrun str([l for l in theString if l != theLetter])
```

Comment: Agreed, if you take the time to learn list comprehension using this problem, it will change your life forever - definitely worth a shot!